# How to remove query string or how to maintain constant URL using URL rewrite

Tags: asp.net

How to maintain constant URL?
  For example:

```
http:// test23232 /temp/temp.aspx?a=1&b=1
```

a,b,query string parameter name get differ dynamically page to page(want to use those parameter but not dispaly for users)

While redirecting ,whatever  the value present after **?** should be removed and final URL displayed to users:

```
http:// test23232 /temp/temp.aspx or  http:// test23232 /temp
```

Or any constant url post login mentioned throughout entire application.

I can acheive this by iframe, but how can I do by doing `web.config` through rule or `global ascx`. 
    or

whatever page redirect

> http : //localhost /test/security / login.aspx 
>   http : //localhost /test/security / main.aspx
>   http : //localhost /test/security / details.aspx

I want to show to browser as

```
http :// localhost / reap/ security /
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Use Session to store the values of a and b and keep the url simple.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is not possible to make entire query string to session variable since it is dynamically creating . Is there any possibility to do changes web.config or global.aspx by creating rule

Comment: A good link on url re-writing http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-outbound-rules-for-url-rewrite-module

Comment: yes gone through the url rewriting. But i want your all suggestion whether is this possible to do using url rewriting.

Comment: I m just redirect to  Response.Redirect(default.aspx?id=1&name="a") and i want to show to browser url as new_index.aspx or any constant page but at the same time i want to show case default.aspx in browser body content and url remain constant as new_index.aspx for every redirect . is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can send the necessary parameter using **post** method instead of **get** method.
More **secure** way of passing them is to store them into **session variable**.

that might make it more "secure" since then the client cannot change the variables by editing the source.

It will depends on how you *really* want to do.

The session parameters will keep on changing dynamically for every request.We can go for cookies.

Yet [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx)  might be useful for url rewriting

Comment: yes but our product based application already developed by using query string redirect..it ll dynamically change every page and for grid edit..its difficult to change entire application query string to session.

Comment: And the session parameters will keep on changing dynamically for every request.We also go for cookies.Yet this link might be useful for url rewriting http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx

Comment: One clarification : Response.Redirect(default.aspx?id=1&name="a") and rewriting to the url show.aspx . again i want to redirect path to new_index without query string . is it possible? or else is it possible to context.path(Redirect path) post redirecting

Comment: I m just redirect to  Response.Redirect(default.aspx?id=1&name="a") and i want to show to browser url as new_index.aspx or any constant page but at the same time i want to show case default.aspx in browser body content and url remain constant as new_index.aspx for every redirect . is this possible?